# Graphic and text position in a button (JavaFX)

Tags: css, button, javafx, alignment

I've got a question:
How can I set a graphic and a text in a specific position inside a button via CSS?I can't find a soulution in google.
Thanks for help :)

Comment: Thanks, that works fine :) But I've got another question: can I set a text in CSS?I tried to set the text for my button with "-fx-text: ...", but this didn't work, and can I set the alignment for a Label in CSS?Thanks for help

Comment: New questions => new questions, not comments.  Read the [CSS reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) and other [JavaFX documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/size_align.htm#JFXLY133), then attempt to solve your issues yourself.  If you are unable to solve the issue with reasonable effort (and I don't mean just a google search), and have a question which has not been asked before, please ask it as a new question which details both your research effort and your solution attempt.